# my csv file is not viewing correctly on Rstudios

Tags: r, csv

I am just learning R and cant figure out why my this csv is not parsing correctly. It is saying that there is 0 observations and 4982 variables. The csv i am using is from https://github.com/gwenfuri2/SleepandLifestyle/blob/main/Sleep_lifestyle.csv

I tried downloading multiple package libraries to see if that was the issue.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(readr)

data = read.csv("https://github.com/gwenfuri2/SleepandLifestyle/blob/main/Sleep_lifestyle.csv")
read.csv(data)
```

[image]

Comment: Try `data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gwenfuri2/SleepandLifestyle/main/Sleep_lifestyle.csv")` . You need to click on raw to get the URL to read.